# Unable to resume activity, App crash after using camera

Tags: android, android-activity, resume, runtimeexception

Who can help me review this bug, In my activity I startActivityForResult (used camera to take image). After taken photo, my activity can't resume. :(

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example/com.example.view.main.PersonActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=998, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example/com.example.view.main.PersonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

--------- Stack trace ---------

    android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-------------------------------

--------- Cause ---------

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=998, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example/com.example.view.main.PersonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2994)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2000)
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-------------------------------
```

In my java-code, at OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String filePath = "";
    switch (requestCode) {
    case MyActivity.RQ_SALE_TAKE_PHOTO:
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null && data.getAction() != null) {
                    Bitmap tempBitmap = null;
                    tempBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    //.....
                }
            } else {
                //DO SOMETHING HERE
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Code call camera :

```
public static File takePhoto(Activity sender, int requestCode) {
    System.gc();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    String fileName = Constants.TEMP_IMG + "_" + DateUtils.getCurrentDateTimeWithFormat(null) + ".jpg";
    File retFile = new File(ExternalStorage.getTakenPhotoPath(sender), fileName);
    if (!retFile.exists())
        try {
            retFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(retFile));
    sender.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    return retFile;
}
```

Can anyone help me to explain the above error, and how to fix this error.

Comment: could you put the code that you call Camera intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the return intent  "`data`" is null

Make sure that you use `startActivityForResult` and the default camera application.

The default Android camera application returns a non-null intent only when passing back a thumbnail in the returned Intent. If you pass EXTRA_OUTPUT with a URL to write to, it will return a null intent and the pictures is in the URL that you passed in.

Comment: Hi Arun C Thomas, data i checked.

Comment: just remove     intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(retFile));

Comment: Hi Arun, with my case "data" is null, and I got image from url after taken photo. But this error i didn't find any line-code in my project

Comment: ok the error  if  error occurs very rarely it will be because that your activity in background is destroyed and "retFile" is not properly saved to saveInstance.. so it will be null.. pLease make sure that  retFile is properly restored

Comment: make sure that retFile is properly restored  using onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: Excuse Arun!. Could you explain to me why "Unable to resume activity"

Comment: When you go to camera from your app the system is consuming more memory and when you changes orientation of your camera or do some thing which will consume more memory the background application(your application) get killed and  it will be regenerated only when the activity result came back So the onCreate of your application will be called that time but the initialization you done in takePhoto function will be lost The life cycle in this case will be like  onCreate->onRestoreInstance->onActivityResult->onResume  soif some thing goes wrong in onActivityResult Unable to resume activity  occur

Comment: Hi Arun, I used onSaveInstanceState() and try-catch in OnActivityResult. I got an exception follow: sales: onActivityResult java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1. I didn't know array? (Maybe array activities?)

Comment: @TCA +1 for the detailed explanation. Giving a link to a more detailed article would help.

Answer (score 0):

Just do startActivity. When you do startActivityForResult, from other launchedactivity, you need to setResult() to your activity.

Now camera activity is not setting any result for you and it crashes in onActivityResult function.

Comment: Sorry Sushil, Normally it will still work, this error occurs very rarely

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, requestCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(photoPath);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Capture Image"),
                            MyActivity.RQ_SALE_TAKE_PHOTO);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Your intent is different.

Comment: :), Normally it will still work, this error occurs very rarely. Could you explain to me why need to change "intent". Thanks Renan!

Comment: It's the same..I've seen it now and there is no difference.